# How to run ionic project on android?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying execute an Ionic project on Android. In the official docs say to execute like this: `ionic platform add android` and `ionic run android`. I made this and all process are executed without any error but the application doesn't start on my device. I tried execute with cordova `cordova run android` and does not work also. My device contain Android API 19 - Samsung Galaxy S4 and adb is executing and device was authorized.

How could I make execute the project on Android ?

**Ionic Info**

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.3.3
Ionic Version: 1.1.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.7
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.3
OS: Windows 7
Node Version: v5.0.0
```

Comment: Try a downgrade to something that isn't node v5 - I had a Cordova project fail yesterday as a result of this; downgrading node fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cordova currently [does not work](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9935) with node.js v5. Downgrading to an earlier version of node should work.

Comment: I've gone all the way back to 0.12.7 to be honest - which works fine :-)